# Saving of nested list of objects fails with JSON post in Grails

Tags: json, list, rest, grails, post

Example application: https://github.com/Hi-Fi/writetable-example-with-grails

In example application, controllers work fine when used through GSP pages or posting with CURL the form. Command with curl:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/junk/team/save" --data "name=team&players"%"5B0"%"5D.firstName=first&players"%"5B0"%"5D.lastName=last&players"%"5B0"%"5D.position=position&create=Create" --compressed.
```

Problem is with identical request using JSON, which creates identical (according dump()) object, but can't save the nested values.

When making following POST with SOAPUI (localhost:8080/junk/api/rest):

```
{
    name: "Team name",
    players: [
        {
             firstName: "Player first name",
             lastName: "Player last name",
             position: "Player position"
        }
    ]
}
```

I just get error:

```
| Error 2014-12-20 21:02:47,050 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an     assertion failure occured
(this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
Message: null id in junk.Player entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
Line | Method
->> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Parent object (Team) is still saved even there's this error. With Hibernate4 whole save fails, so updating to it wasn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is explicitly connect "Team" with each "Player" like

```
team.players.each {it.team = team}
```

With form posting, this step is made automatically, but for some reason not with JSON. Player object at after Team object creation in JSON:

```
<junk.Player@76f8539e firstName=first lastName=last position=position deleted=false errors=grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors $changedProperties=null id=null version=null team=null>
```

And with form POST:

```
<junk.Player@1ba14c1b firstName=first lastName=last position=position deleted=false errors=grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors $changedProperties=null id=null version=null team=junk.Team : (unsaved)>
```

This might not be the "right" solution, so I'm still happy to hear if there's better solution for nested one-to-many -lists.